# How do I write to file descriptor 3 instead of stdout in .NET 6 on Linux?

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core

I'm using .NET 6 on Ubuntu 22.04. What is the equivalent C# code to the following Bash code?

```bash
echo 'Hello, World!' >&3
```

Normally, in C# I'd use code like `Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");` to write to stdout. But here, I need to write to file descriptor 3 instead of stdout.

I was able to find some Stack Overflow answers, but they're quite old and deal with Windows APIs which I don't think applies to what I'm trying to do.

I should clarify too that for my use case, redirecting standout output to another file descriptor as I start the .NET process isn't an option. This is is because I need to be able to write to stdout for one purpose, stderr for another, and file descriptor 3 for another. Three purposes in total. This is because the process must be able to be started by a framework that deals with stdout, stderr, and file descriptor 3 these ways. It needs to be compatible.

Comment: Maybe this is an XY problem? What are you trying to do? In C# you'd normally not use file descriptors directly like that. If file descriptor 3 is a file then it should've been opened via FileStream, if it is for communication via pipes then it should've been opened via `AnonymousPipeServerStream` or `NamedPipeServerStream`

Comment: @Petrusion Sorry. I actually kept my question as focused as possible without explaining my overall goal because in my experience, too much extra detail gets questions closed. Looks like I might have to expand more though. I'm trying to make a C# action for the OpenWhisk framework using the "generic binary" interface (https://github.com/apache/openwhisk-runtime-go/blob/master/docs/ACTION.md#generic). That involves writing to file descriptor 3 (instead of stdout) for the result of your computation. I don't have experience with pipes, so there might be something I'm missing here.

Comment: In the OpenWhisk project, the ActionLoop protocol is what enables the generic binary approach. We make runtimes for different programming languages and in order to implement the ActionLoop protocol, we need to have our runtime link to file descriptor 3. Here's an example of that already implemented for Ruby (https://github.com/apache/openwhisk-runtime-ruby/blob/master/core/ruby2.6ActionLoop/lib/launcher.rb). Note line 26 where it has the code `out = IO.new(3)`.

Comment: I looked into this a bit more, and assuming the library you're writing is a parent process to the C# application and it created an inheritable pipe with FD3, then *maybe* something like `using AnonymousPipeClientStream pipe = new(PipeDirection.Out, "3");` could possibly work?

Comment: @petrusion Based on my understanding of how the OpenWhisk project uses file descriptors, that example you show makes sense. It's actually the opposite by the way regarding parent/child process. I'm assuming by parent process you mean the one that starts my C# process. It's going to be a Go program that is the parent process that starts my C# program in a separate process. And the Go program wires up the pipes as needed. My C# program is expected to interact with the pipes as the Go program dictates. That's the OpenWhisk framework. I'll give that example code a shot and follow up. ty

Comment: I did mean to say that the C# app is a child process and that the OpenWhisk thingee would be the parent process. Sorry for the confusion, I wrote that comment very late in the night

Comment: Follow up: `AnonymousPipeClientStream` did not work for me but `StreamWriter`, in the answer, did work. With the former, I got errors like `System.IO.IOException: Invalid pipe handle`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to achieve this by writing to `/proc/self/fd/3`

Use a StreamWriter:

```
using (StreamWriter outputFile = new StreamWriter("/proc/self/fd/3"))
{
    outputFile.WriteLine("Test");
}
```

Otherwise, you could make a system call to echo, using the command you referenced above, or this...

```
Process.Start(@"echo Test > /proc/self/fd/3");
```

Comment: This worked for me. I used the first example with `StreamWriter`. I was able to run the program with `3> some_file.txt` and see the output there. I did have to add a call to `Flush` on the stream in order to see the output end up in the file in real time.